plotting only points that are stable from a time series and perform linear regression
I have two questions that I put in one help request. so I hope it will not make this overcrowded.
I spend quite some time figuring this out but not successful so far. I am trying to plot only points from a series of data that are close to each other so not the transitions (see below plot). Probably I need an if condition that says if x(2)-x(1)<0.005 plot and if not do not plot. Later I want to do a linear regression on these points (thats why I want to exclude transitions). Can you please help me how to do the plotting with this condition and do linear regression.

This is my code:

# which value you want to use or plot reading from log data
desired_field1= "x y Box"
desired_value1 = "x1 [um]"
desired_field2= "x y Box"
desired_value2 =  "x3 [um]"
desired_field3= "LM Position"
desired_value3 =  "Z [um]"


# extracting desired data from logging
data=pd.read_excel(r"test2.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
data = data[(data['_time'] < '2024-05-21T09:49:37.6089875Z') & (data['_time'] > '2024-05-21T09:43:31.7141954Z')] #selecting desired time interval
data_measurement1 = data.loc[data['_measurement'] == desired_field1]
data_field1 = data_measurement1.loc[data['_field'] == desired_value1]
data_measurement2 = data.loc[data['_measurement'] == desired_field2]
data_field2 = data_measurement2.loc[data['_field'] == desired_value2]
data_measurement3 = data.loc[data['_measurement'] == desired_field3]
data_field3 = data_measurement3.loc[data['_field'] == desired_value3]
values1 = list(data_field1['_value']) #values we are interested in
values2 = list(data_field2['_value'])
values3 = list(data_field3['_value'])
#....

mean_xs = [(g + h) / 2 for g, h in zip(values1, values2)]
LM_mean = [50-x for x in mean_xs]

#start plotting
data_field1['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_field1['_time'].str.split().str[-1])
data_field2['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_field2['_time'].str.split().str[-1])
data_field3['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_field3['_time'].str.split().str[-1])
plt.plot(data_field1['_time'], values1, '-', label = desired_value1)
plt.plot(data_field2['_time'], values2, '-', label = desired_value2 )
plt.plot(data_field3['_time'], values3, '-', label = desired_value3)


plt.xlabel('time [D hh:mm]')
plt.ylabel(' x [um] MCS')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.gca().yaxis.grid(True)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(LM_mean, values3, 'o')


example data:
9988   2024-05-21T09:46:00.1164445Z  1294.005333
9989   2024-05-21T09:46:01.1115275Z  1294.005333
9990   2024-05-21T09:46:02.1254956Z  1294.005667
9991   2024-05-21T09:46:03.1191685Z  1294.005667
9992   2024-05-21T09:46:04.1325494Z  1294.005333
9993   2024-05-21T09:46:05.1268794Z  1294.005333
9994   2024-05-21T09:46:06.1409297Z  1294.005333
9995   2024-05-21T09:46:07.1346292Z  1294.005000
9996   2024-05-21T09:46:08.1488069Z  1294.005333
9997   2024-05-21T09:46:09.1417524Z  1294.005333
9998   2024-05-21T09:46:10.1563002Z  1294.005333
9999   2024-05-21T09:46:11.1692835Z  1294.005333
10000  2024-05-21T09:46:12.1642492Z  1332.747333
10001  2024-05-21T09:46:13.1977216Z  1344.011333
10002  2024-05-21T09:46:14.1926256Z  1344.012000
10003  2024-05-21T09:46:15.2062685Z  1344.011667
10004  2024-05-21T09:46:16.2200463Z  1344.011667
10005  2024-05-21T09:46:17.2339343Z  1344.012000
10006  2024-05-21T09:46:18.2479639Z  1344.012000
10007  2024-05-21T09:46:19.2405515Z  1344.012000
10008  2024-05-21T09:46:20.2556817Z  1344.012000

I have tried searching for this but was not successful
Update on how I solved this, note I have two time series and wanted to plot them against each other for same timestep:
idxSteps = np.array(np.where(np.abs(x.diff()) > 0.05)) 
idxSteps2 = np.array(np.where(np.abs(y.diff()) > 0.05))
previousStep = 0 # init the previous step
xIdx = list()
xMid = list() # init list for x
yMid = list() # ==/== for y
i=0
for currentStep in idxSteps[0]:# for every step detected
   if currentStep != previousStep:
           if currentStep in idxSteps2[0]:# and if they are not the same as previousStep
               dummyX = x[previousStep:currentStep] # get the data between these two steps
               dummyY = y[previousStep:currentStep] # ==/==
               xIdx.append((previousStep+currentStep)//2)
               xMid.append(dummyX.mean())
               yMid.append(dummyY.mean()) # append the statistical mode (most recurring value)
               previousStep = currentStep
               assign previousStep as currentStep for the next loop


Sorry for taking too long, I hope I can assist you further with the following adjusted answer.
Here's the code as a dump, I will explain the code step by step in the section after the code:
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 
df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"])
idxSteps = np.array(np.where(np.abs(df["Data"].diff()) > 20)) # search for drops as the abs of the difference
previousStep = 0 # init the previous step
xIdx = list()
xMid = list() # init list for x
yMid = list() # ==/== for y
for currentStep in [idxSteps[0], len(df.index)]: # for every step detected
    if not isinstance(currentStep, int):
        currentStep= currentStep[0]
    if currentStep != previousStep: # and if they are not the same as previousStep
        dummyX = df["Datetime"].loc[previousStep:currentStep] # get the data between these two steps
        dummyY = df["Data"].loc[previousStep:currentStep] # ==/==
        xIdx.append((previousStep+currentStep)//2)
        xMid.append(dummyX.mean()) # append to the average of the date to the x list
        yMid.append(dummyY.mode()) # append the statistical mode (most recurring value)
        previousStep = currentStep # assign previousStep as currentStep for the next loop
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df["Datetime"], df["Data"])
plt.scatter(xMid, yMid, marker = "x", color = "red")
fit = np.polyfit(xIdx, yMid, 1) # fit
plt.plot(df["Datetime"], np.polyval(fit, df["Datetime"].index), "k--") # plot fit
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks = 3, maxticks = 7)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(locator) 
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter) 
plt.grid()


To start off, I saved the data you included in the post in an excel file under the following structure:

I can read this with the pd.read_excel() function, keeping in mind that the datetime column needs to be converted with pd.to_datetime()
Then we basically do the following:

calculate the derivative of the data to detect the jumps
get the sections between jumps
calculate index, datetime and y coordinates
We assume that the data starts and ends with flat data and therefore start from the beggining of the data (previousStep = 0) and loop until the last element in the dataframe for currentStep in [idxSteps[0], len(df.index)]
After calculating the stuff we need, we set previousStep = currentStep and then the loop start again

Some important information:

The reason why we save the index, is because we want to use it for the regression, as regressions don't like datetime formats
To get the y coordinates, I chose the statistical mode: the most recurring value
To get the x coordinates, I chose the mean of the section. If you want the x coordinate to be defined at the beginning of the jump, then go with min(). Alternatively, at the end, go with max()

Here's how the end result looks like:

A note to you: please read and understand my code. Don't just copy paste and hope for the best. Check for the intermediate data that I am generating with the code.
This code so far only works for the section of data that you posted. It might not work on others, which is why you understanding how this solution was thought out is important! So you can come up with your own solution!

Hi Tino, thanks for your answer again. I am not sure why when I use this to my data the xMid is produced as NaN and only has two values while I expect at least an array with length of 50. the issue with the xMid,append producing NaN data.

Are there any nans in your data? Also, did you check if the jump detection could be imporved? How does df["Data"].diff() look like?

yes, I run print(df["Data"].diff()) and it shows indeed some NaN values.

Can you copy that portion of the data into the question?

I fixed the NaN issue in diffvalues. The issue is in this part of the code that produce Nan for xMid.

this part: for currentStep in [idxSteps[0], len(df.index)]: .....

Hey, I can help you as much as I can, but I'm afraid some stuff you will have to figure out yourself.. without the data it is very difficult (impossible actually) for me to reproduce what you are seeing

I have attached the diff values to the question.

@KS I cannot import an image as data and I do not need the diff values, I need the raw values

I debugged through the code and I think its not normal that it shows this value for dummyX when I print it in the step and after its calculated it just print this: Series([], Name: _time, dtype: object). so it looks like it doesn't write the data between the steps

I think I am not allowed to share my excel data here. So not sure how to share the raw data.

In my opinion, you'll need to figure this one out yourself. It's hard to ask for specific answers without supplying specific data. On the other question you asked, it's quite easy, since it's a general problem

@KS see this for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples
